# want to show separate data on monthly base

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

collection is obtrained like this

```
Collection {#241 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Oct-2016" => Collection {#225 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Event {#243 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "Nov-2016" => Collection {#236 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Event {#244 ▶}
        1 => Event {#245 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to show data like .

```
Oct 2016
   event 1
Nov 2016
   event 1
   event 2
```

i am new in laravel kindly help me how to show collection key in title Oct-2016 and list of each key collection   in blade

Comment: output looks backwards oct has1 event nov 2. aside that a simple loop will do this

Comment: yes i update my question kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Laravel collections implement php's iterable functionality. In other words, you can just use foreach loops. This will give you the basic idea.

```
foreach ($collection as $month => $events)
{
    var_dump($month);
    foreach ($events as $event)
    {
        var_dump($event);
    }
}
```